# Equality of unwrapped optional arrays in Swift

Tags: swift

I believe the following to be a bug, and have filed a Radar report on it
(#17340397). However, since Apple doesn't give much feedback on bug reports,
I'm here to ask smarter people than myself what they think.

Consider this:

```
let a: Array<Int>? = [1,2,3]
let b: Array<Int>? = [1,2,3]

a! == b!
```

That's false.  Why is it false?

At first I thought array comparison just doesn't work this way, but if I
explicitly unwrap these first, then it works:

```
let a2 = a!
let b2 = b!

a2 == b2
```

That's true.

What am I missing?  It looks like there is some special magic happening when
the new assignment is made, but why?

Thanks for the help, or if you can't help then thanks for the commiseration. ;-)

Comment: What happens if you wrap the unwrapping in parentheses? Like so: `(a!) == (b!)`. My theory is that the compiler might remove som white space making it `a !== b!` which should in fact be `false`.

Comment: @KasperMoerch `(a!) == (b!)` give me false in playground

Comment: Then I it must be a bug, yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug

`a2 == b!` is `true` but `b! == a2` is `false`, which doesn't make any sense

```
xcrun swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> let a: Array<Int>? = [1]
a: Int[]? = size=1 {
  [0] = 1
}
  2> let b: Array<Int>? = [1]
b: Int[]? = size=1 {
  [0] = 1
}
  3> let a2 = a!
a2: Int[] = size=1 {
  [0] = 1
}
  4> let b2 = b!
b2: Int[] = size=1 {
  [0] = 1
}
  5> 
  6> a2 == b!
$R1: Bool = true
  7> b! == a2
$R2: Bool = false
  8> (a2 == b!) == (b! == a2)
$R3: (Bool) = false
```

---

I think it is caused by same bug with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238478/what-is-the-slice-compare-logic-in-swift/24239556#24239556)

```
  9> import Foundation
 10> a2 == b!
$R9: Bool = true
 11> b! == a2
<REPL>:11:4: error: ambiguous use of operator '=='
b! == a2
   ^
Swift.==:1:19: note: found this candidate
@transparent func ==(lhs: CConstVoidPointer, rhs: CConstVoidPointer) -> Bool
                  ^
Foundation.==:1:6: note: found this candidate
func ==(lhs: NSObject, rhs: NSObject) -> Bool
     ^

 11>
```

The compiler somehow pick `func ==(lhs: CConstVoidPointer, rhs: CConstVoidPointer) -> Bool` to call for `b! == a2`, which obviously is incorrect because it compare the pointer equality not content equality.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report: [rdar://17340722](http://openradar.appspot.com/17340722)

Comment: Thanks.  According to the "more radars get more attention" theory we now have at least two points!