# Bug in Swift's notion of Array equality?

Tags: arrays, swift

Try this:

```
    let url1 = NSURL(string: "foo bar")
    let url2 = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")
    var arr1 = NSURL[]()
    var arr2 = NSURL[]()
    // one order
    arr1 += url1
    arr1 += url2
    // other order
    arr2 += url2
    arr2 += url1
    // equality test
    println(arr1 == arr2) // true!?
```

After some experimentation, I think this has to do with Optionals. `url1` comes back as nil, so to form an array of both urls, Swift has to treat these arrays (I'm guessing) as arrays of `Optional<NSURL>`. But I still think it's a bug; it's as if the notion of comparing an array of optional NSURLs causes Swift to throw up its hands somehow... And, one might argue, it's a bug in another sense too, because I explicitly typed these arrays as `NSURL[]`; I didn't say `NSURL?[]`, so why is Swift permitting an Optional to go into them in the first place?

I'm wondering if anyone has noticed anything similar that might throw light on the matter. (I don't think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260900/equality-of-unwrapped-optional-arrays-in-swift) is related, though of course I could be wrong.)

**EDIT** Some people have expressed an inability to reproduce the issue, so I've posted an example project at https://github.com/mattneub/SwiftArrayEqualityTest

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, if `url1` is an optional you can't add it to the array without a compiler error. In my playground, `let url1 = NSURL(string: "foo bar")` throws an exception, if I add a type like this: `let url1:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "foo bar")`. Then `url1` is `nil` but the compiler complains about adding it to the array. Either way I can't get to the compare line at all

Comment: @JackWu Could everybody please forget playgrounds? They are seriously broken, and they don't behave correctly or identically to an app. The only place that matters is apps. Real, compiled apps. My code is from an app. And it is based on a much more elaborate, commonly encountered real-life situation. It is not an artifice; it is boiled down to an artifice just to demonstrate the issue compactly.

Comment: Well Swift is as beta as Playground is, so file a radar? I don't know why you're expecting Swift to behave well given that playgrounds are seriously broken

Comment: In my testing, it crashes at `arr1+=url2` in obc_retain() with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Prior to that, the array reports that is has a non-nil pointer to an NSObject.  Is suspect it's sending retain to a junk pointer when it copies the array for the second append.  Fine bugs abounds.

Comment: @matt Please make sure you file a radar. Only solution for now would be to check to see if the NSURL is `nil` before adding it to the array.

Comment: @NateCook Oh, no, it's much more insidious than that. In my real-life app, none of the URLs is nil. But they are all optional, and this seems to be the cause of the problem there. The example here is merely a highly simplified reduced test case. Don't you worry, I've filed a bug.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, all instances from the Objective-C APIs (essentially any UI* or NS* class) are actually optional, despite not appearing to be so via declaration, since Objective-C types can always be `nil`. An array of `NSURL` is essentially an array of implicitly unwrapped optional `NSURL`s, or `NSURL![]`.

(I explained more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24440135/59541).)

So it isn't a bug that the array can take a `nil` value, but it *is* a bug that the two evaluate to equal. Get thee to [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com/).